# Showing a Div When Checkbox Is Clicked In JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code seems to show a div that disappears when the box is checked.

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript">
    $(function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.myClass').toggle(!this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Check Here<input type="checkbox"></legend>
    <span class="myClass">
        <p>This is the text.</p>
    </span>
</fieldset>
```

How can I change it to show the box ONLY when it's checked instead of before it's checked?

Edit: Changing it to/from `!this.checked/this.checked`, is not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `this.checked` instead of `!this.checked`.

```
$(function() {
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
         $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.myClass').toggle(this.checked);
     });
});
```

You'd set `.myClass` to be initially hidden also:

```
span.myClass {
    display:none;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DN3yC/9/)